# Problems with running .sh files

Tags: command-line

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I can't seem to be able to run .sh files.

I have marked it as executable in properties and I tried to run it through the GUI. However, the terminal just flashed on the screen and doesn't do anything.

When I try to run the file through the terminal I get the following error :

```
Minecraft_Installer_20.sh: 2: Minecraft_Installer_20.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

Comment: please tell us where you got this file from?

Comment: Please post this file on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and link to it in your original question.

Comment: sounds like a bash/dash/sh/zsh difference

Comment: This might be because the old minecraft .sh file or the java program running in your machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try downloading and running the file again. It works for me.

Here is [Minecraft_Installer_20.sh](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1162676/) (as of August 23rd 2012).

---

**1** - Copy and paste the text in a new file named `Minecraft_Installer_20.sh` in your home directory.

**2** - Now, open Terminal and run the following command:

```
bash ~/Minecraft_Installer_20.sh
```

---

It should work!

Comment: i am having the same problem with mcedit. can you help me?